# Unit testing Jersey Resources with Guice injected fields

Tags: java, junit, jersey, guice

I have a Jersey Resource that I want to test with JUnit. The resource uses Guice Providers to inject certain fields:

```
@Path("/example/")
class ExampleResource {
    @Inject
    Provider<ExampleActionHandler> getMyExampleActionHandlerProvider;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ExamplePojo> getExampleList() {
        ExampleActionHandler handler = getMyExampleActionHandlerProvider.get();
        handler.doSomething();
    ...
```

This all works beautifully when using a real server to serve the API, however testing it is problematic.

My test class currently looks something like:

```
public class ApiTest extends JerseyTest {

  public ApiTest() throws Exception {
    super();
    ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = new ApplicationDescriptor();
    appDescriptor.setContextPath("/api");
    appDescriptor.setRootResourcePackageName("com.my.package.name");
    super.setupTestEnvironment(appDescriptor);
  }

  @Test
  public void testHelloWorld() throws Exception {
    String responseMsg = webResource.path("example/").get(String.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("{}", responseMsg);
  }
}
```

Clearly, Guice isn't getting the opportunity to initialize the fields in `ExampleResource` so that the `handler.doSomething()` call doesn't result in a NullPointerException.

Is there a way to tell Jersey to instantiate the ExampleResource class using Guice so that the Provider works?

Comment: I know this is a little late, but on the off chance you're still seeing this, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @minichate did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to break the tests to few steps. You need to create the injector you're configuring the service with and test that injector (see [Testing Guice Servlet bindings](http://www.eishay.com/2011/10/testing-guice-servlet-bindings.html) and [Testing Guice can init servlets](http://www.eishay.com/2011/10/testing-guice-can-init-servlets.html)). Using these tests you make sure you have the right bindings in place. 
Once you have the injector, get the ApplicationDescriptor object from it with

```
ExampleResource exampleResource = injector.getInstance(ExampleResource.class);
Assert.assertEquals(myList, getExampleList());
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that none of the magic that Jersey does is available -- such as @DefaultValue() annotated fields. I actually _have_ gotten this working the way that I want it to, just trying to wrap it up into something post-able on SO.